# The Problem with Operator Compactness

Tags: functional-analysis

> For what $a\in (0,1)$ does the operator
> $$A:L_2[0,1]\to L_2[0,1], \; (Ax)(t)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x(s)}{|t-s|^a}ds$$
> compact?

$$Ax=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x(s)}{|t-s|^a}ds\Rightarrow \left \| Ax \right \|=\int_{0}^{1}\left | \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x(s)}{|t-s|^a}ds \right |^2dt\leq \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{|x(s)|^2}{|t-s|^{2a}}dsdt=$$
$$=\int_{0}^{1}ds|x(s)|^2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{|t-s|^{2a}}=\int_{0}^{1}ds|x(s)|^2\left ( \int_{0}^{s}\frac{dt}{(s-t)^{2a}}+\int_{s}^{1}\frac{dt}{(t-s)^{2a}} \right )\leq \frac{2}{1-2a}\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^{1-2a}\left \| x \right \|, \; a<\frac{1}{2}$$

I was able to prove for $a<1/2$, but not sure if it's correct

I also cannot prove for $a\geq 1/2$. Even if we prove it, what does this give us?

The textbook answer is $a\in (0,1)$, but I can't completely trust this answer. *Could you help me get the correct answer?*

An operator will be compact if and only if

$$K(t,s)=\frac{1}{|t-s|^a}\Rightarrow \left \| K \right \|^2<\infty \Leftrightarrow \int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{dtds}{|t-s|^{2a}}$$

$$a<\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow \int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{dtds}{|t-s|^{2a}}=\int\limits_{0}^{1}ds\left ( \int\limits_{0}^{s} \frac{dt}{(s-t)^{2a}}+\int\limits_{s}^{1}\frac{dt}{(t-s)^{2a}}\right )=$$
$$=\int\limits_{0}^{1}ds\left ( \frac{s^{1-2a}}{1-2a}+\frac{(1-s)^{1-2a}}{1-2a} \right )\leq \int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{2}{1-2a}\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^{1-2a}ds<\infty $$

We have shown that for $a<1/2$ $Ax(t)$ is compact

$$a=\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow t\in \left ( 0,s-\frac{1}{n} \right )\cup \left ( s+\frac{1}{n},1 \right )\Rightarrow$$
$$\Rightarrow \Delta _n=\left \{ t\in \left ( 0,s-\frac{1}{n} \right )\cup \left ( s+\frac{1}{n},1 \right );s\in (0,1)\right \}\Rightarrow$$
$$\Rightarrow \int\limits_{\Delta _n}K^2(t,s)dtds=\int\limits_{0}^{1}ds\left ( \int\limits_{0}^{s-1/n}\frac{dt}{s-t}+\int\limits_{s+1/n}^{1}\frac{dt}{t-s} \right )=$$
$$=\int\limits_{0}^{1}ds\left ( \ln ns+\ln (n(1-s)) \right )=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\ln\left ( n^2s(1-s) \right )ds=$$
$$=s\ln\left ( n^2(s-s^2) \right )\Bigg|_0^1-\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{s(1-2s)}{s-s^2}ds=\ln n^2-2$$
At $n\rightarrow \infty $ there will be $\Delta _n\to [0,1]^2$, but $\displaystyle{\int\limits_{[0,1]^2}K^2(t,s) dtds\to \infty }$, therefore, for $a=1/2$ $Ax(t)$ is not compact. Because the

$$K(t,s)\Bigg|_{a=1/2}<K(t,s)\Bigg|_{a>1/2}$$
For any $a\geq 1/2$ $Ax(t)$ is not compact

**I managed to solve it!**

[image: I got the information from here]

Comment: In your proof for $1/2$, you are missing the $t$. The first equality is for a given $t$, which you need to specify.

Comment: You are proving that $A$ is bounded. If $A$ is compact it is also bounded, but the converse is not necessarily true. But please check your computations. You keep forgetting to square norms. Remember: $\lVert Ax\rVert=\sqrt{\int_0^1 |Ax|^2}$. Don't forget those square roots. You forget them at several points.

Comment: Any ideas for $a\geq 1/2$?

Comment: @Dmitry How about you correct your mistakes for the case $a < 1/2$ as mentioned above first?

Comment: Simple bugs that do not affect anything and which I have already corrected. If I ask you to help me with $a\geq 1/2$, then why should I still talk about $a<1/2$?

Comment: For $a < 1/2$ the operator is even Hilbert-Schmidt by kernel's theorem. For $a \ge 1/2$ you need to represent this operator as a limit of compact operators. Complete solution can be found in Weidmann, "Linear Operators in Hilbert Spaces", 6.3, example 3. The answer is correct.

Comment: You have shown that for $a=1/2$ is not Hilbert-Schmidt, but it still can be compact.

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349325/operator-on-l2-0-1-defined-by-convolution-with-x-y-alpha/3564205#3564205